# Why does query_to_xml return an error for a volatile query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, volatile

I'd like to understand why something like this doesn't work in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT query_to_xml('CREATE TABLE my_table (my_column INTEGER)', FALSE, TRUE, '')
```

It gives `ERROR:  CREATE TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function`. Fair enough - but when I checked the signature for  `query_to_xml`, it *is* marked as volatile:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.query_to_xml(
    query text,
    nulls boolean,
    tableforest boolean,
    targetns text)
    RETURNS xml
    LANGUAGE 'internal'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE STRICT PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS [...]
```

Follow-up question: If this isn't allowed, is there any other way to run a dynamic volatile query without PL/PgSQL?

Comment: To run arbitrary dynamic SQL, PL/pgSQL is your only choice. Or you can generate the SQL in your application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING):

> The following functions map the contents of relational tables to XML
> values.

That means you can't use this function for a CREATE TABLE statement, just SELECT data from a table and turn that into an XML.

The error message however, could be better, I agree.

Comment: Agreed about the error message but in some ways it seems to be closer to the truth than the documentation. For example, this is allowed: `SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT 1 AS value; SELECT 2 AS value', FALSE, TRUE, '')` but this isn't: `SELECT query_to_xml('SELECT 1 AS value; CREATE TABLE my_table (my_column INTEGER); SELECT 2 AS value', FALSE, TRUE, '')`

Comment: DDL is not allowed, I'm not even sure about the RETURNING data from DML statements. Multiple statements definitely won't work because this would result in multiple result sets and this function can only handle a single set.

Comment: True, multiple statements won't work in the sense that only the resultset from the last one is used. They are allowed (as per first example in comment above) but not sure whether all would actually be executed. Agree from the results that DML isn't allowed but still not clear on what causes the error - perhaps a non-volatile function is being called internally?